# Get data from custom select field and paste to New Order E-mail - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my Checkout page I have an additional select type field with several options to choose from:

> select name="_billing_rola"
> option value="option1" > Example 1
> option value="option2" > Example 2
> option value="option3" > Example 3

I'm trying to insert this information into a new order email. So far I've been able to get a half-way result with code like this:

```
// Short code [woo_mb_custom_code type="rola"]
if (isset($attr['type']) && $attr['type'] == 'rola') {
    $order_id = method_exists($order, 'get_id') ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    $rola = get_post_meta($order_id, "_billing_rola", true);

    echo '<p>' . $rola . '</p>';
}
```

As you can see, $rola displays values from the option value items i.e. option1, option2, option3 depending on what the customer chooses.

What I would like to get is that the last line of code displays Example 1, Example 2, Example 3 values depending on the selection.

Comment: Well then you need to "translate" the actual value into your desired text at this point - for example by using a lookup array, `$billing_rola_texts = ['option1' => 'Example 1', ...];`, and then access `$billing_rola_texts[$rola]`

Comment: Thank you for your correct answer. Your solution works as I wanted.